# Baking polymer clay phone case

Tags: polymer-clay

I've been trying to make a polymer clay cover for my phone case and have been having a horrible time.

The baking directions say 275 but the plastic is melting and warping the case. I want it to be strong on there, so I thought baking directly on it would help. Also with Bake & Bond Sculpey to hold it to the case. Any suggestions to make this work?

I'm using "Premo".

Comment: Are you following some sort of guide for it?

Comment: Are you creating the entire phone case from scratch, or trying to bake clay decorations on an existing case?

Comment: When you say "warping the case", you mean you are baking the phone case along with the polymer clay?

Comment: I did a little digging. Most of the guides I found for this superglue the decorations onto the case after the fact. I don't know that the clay is malleable enough to use as the entire case.

Answer (score 1):

Premo is one of the stronger kinds, so you're making the right choice there. I have only recently started using premo mixed my older sculpey III and have found it can cure as low as 225, but you'll obviously have to bake longer.

Comment: But does that temperature prevent the plastic from melting? If not, then it's not much of a solution :D